# Check if string contains equal number of curly brackets in python

Tags: python, string

I want to check if the string contains equal number of brackets like let's say I have a string like this

> Hi {{name}} how are you?

so I want to check if curly brackets around the name are equal or not.

I have tried the stack implementation but that works well only if string contains only brackets, not any other character

Comment: please share your stack implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only curly brackets can appear in a string:

```
def check(s, left='{', right='}'):
    b = 0

    for c in s:
        if c == left:
            b += 1
        if c == right:
            if b == 0:
                return False
            b -= 1

    return b == 0
```

It is a simplified version of the stack implementation. If you have other kinds of brackets you want to check you'd need an actual stack and just skip non-brackets characters in your checks.

Comment: Yevhen Kuzmovych thanks what if i want to check exactly count of brackets like if there is 2 opening and 2 closing brackets then only consider this as valid

Comment: Think about what `b` represents in this implementation. You can add some checks during iterations. For instance if `b>2` there's something wrong (i.e. `"{{{hello}}}"`). If `b==1 and c != left` there's something wrong (i.e. `"{a{hello}}"`). Etc.

Comment: Yevhen Kuzmovych that i can understand and It works but it did not work if string has more than one variables like hello {{name}} {{second_name}} etc

Answer (score 1):

The awnser of @Yevhen Kusmovych  is working but I want to share another attempt for this problem. I want to show an attempt with regex and recursion:

```py
import re

def compare_brackets(left, right, test_str, matches):
    regex = r"{}[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*{}".format(left, right)
    match = re.search(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
    if match:
        test_str = test_str[:match.start()] + 'a' + test_str[match.end():]
        matches.append(match.group())
        _, test_str = compare_brackets(left, right, test_str, matches)
    return len(matches), test_str

    
def bad_brackets(left, right, leftover_str, bad_matches):
    regex = r"{}|{}".format(left, right)
    bad_match = re.search(regex, leftover_str, re.MULTILINE)
    if bad_match:
        leftover_str = leftover_str[:bad_match.start()] + 'a' + leftover_str[bad_match.end():]
        bad_matches.append(bad_match.group())
        bad_brackets(left, right, leftover_str, bad_matches)
    return len(bad_matches), leftover_str
```

I implemented two functions which call themself recursivly to find first all good brackets starting from the first inner brackets match and removing them from the string. After all valid Brackets are deleted from the string the second function uses the leftover string and searches for invalid brackets.

I tested for three different strings:

```py
count_of_brackets, test_str = compare_brackets('{','}', "Hi {{name}} how are you", [])
count_of_bad_brackets, leftover = bad_brackets('{','}', test_str, [])
print('Found {} valid bracket pairs and {} broken brackets'.format(count_of_brackets, count_of_bad_brackets))

count_of_brackets, test_str = compare_brackets('{','}', "Hi {{{name}}} how are} you",[])
count_of_bad_brackets, leftover = bad_brackets('{','}', test_str, [])
print('Found {} valid bracket pairs and {} broken brackets'.format(count_of_brackets, count_of_bad_brackets))

count_of_brackets, test_str = compare_brackets('{','}', "Hi {{{my name}}} is your {{bodypart}} ok", [])
count_of_bad_brackets, leftover = bad_brackets('{','}', test_str, [])
print('Found {} valid bracket pairs and {} broken brackets'.format(count_of_brackets, count_of_bad_brackets))
```

**output**

```sh
Found 2 valid bracket pairs and 0 broken brackets
Found 3 valid bracket pairs and 1 broken brackets
Found 5 valid bracket pairs and 0 broken brackets
```

Comment: My solution does work for multiple bracket pairs. But regex is also a useful consideration for this task.

Comment: Oh yes I see your change ```b -= 1``` now